# Php Kendo UI With datasource (CRUD)

Tags: javascript, php, kendo-ui, crud

I am struggling to get the functionality of CRUD using the Kendo UI? My create and Update options dont seem to work but my read does, any help? I have been through plenty of tutorials but simply just cant get this to work.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code, this is my Index.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="example">
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                batch: true,
                transport: {

                    read: "data/ussd.php"
                },

                update: {
                    url: "data/ussd.php",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                create: {

                    url: "data/create.php",
                    type: "PUT"
                },
                parameterMap: function(options, operation){
                    if(operation !== "read" && option.models){
                        return{models : kendo.string(options.models)}
                    }
                },

                pageSize: 20,
                schema: {
                    data: "data",
                    model: {
                        id: "id",
                        fields: {
                             id: {editable: false, nullable: true},
                             msisdn: {editable: true, type: "number"},
                             company: {editable: true},
                             description: {editable: true},
                             ussd: {editable: true},
                             updated: {editable: true, type: "date"},
                             added: {editable: true, type: "date"}
                        }
                    }
                },

                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true

            });

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource:  dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,

            height: 500,
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            columns: [

                { field: "id", title: "ID", width: "45px" },
                { field: "msisdn", title: "MSISDN", width: "75px" },
                { field: "company", title: "Company", width: "100px" },
                { field: "description", title:"Description", width: "100px" },
                { field: "ussd", title: "USSD", width: "100px" },
                { field: "updated", title: "Updated", width: "100px" },
                { field: "added", title: "Added", width: "100px" },
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "140px" }],

            schema: {
                model: { id: "id" }
            },

            editable: "inline",
            navigable: true
        });


    });



</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are setting `batch` to true that means that create, update and delete will not be invoked until you call `saveChanges` in Grid object. Are you explicitly invoking it? Try also setting `batch` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work another way.

Comment: Do you know that you can answer your own question? If you think that your solution is relevant, please do it. Otherwise remove the question since it is not going to help other people.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i changed, basically URL and type was incorrect and not following the correct path

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

            transport: {

                read: "data/whitelist.php?type=read",
                update: {url:"data/whitelist.php?type=update", type:"POST"},
                create: {url:"data/whitelist.php?=create",type:"POST"},
                destroy: {url:"data/whitelist.php?type=destroy",type:"POST"}
            },


            batch: false,
            pageSize: 20,
            schema: {

                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    fields: {
                        id: {editable: false, nullable: true},
                        msisdn: {editable: true, type: "number"},
                        company: {editable: true},
                        description: {editable: true},
                        ussd: {editable: true},
                        updated: {editable: true, type: "date"},
                        added: {editable: true, type: "date"}
                    }
                }
            },

            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true

        });

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource:  dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,

            height: 430,
            toolbar: [{name: "create", text: "Add New"}, "save", "cancel"],
            columns: [

                { field: "id", title: "ID", width: "26px" },
                { field: "msisdn", title: "MSISDN", width: "50px" },
                { field: "company", title: "Company", width: "65px" },
                { field: "description", title:"Description", width: "65px" },
                { field: "ussd", title: "USSD", width: "50px" },
                { field: "updated", title: "Updated", width: "70px" },
                { field: "added", title: "Added", width: "70px" },
                { command: [{text:"Edit", name:"edit"}, {text:"Delete",name:"destroy"}], title: " ", width: "80px" }],

            editable: "inline",
            navigable: true


        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{                    read: "data/ussd.php"
                },

                update: {
                    url: "data/ussd.php",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                create: {

                    url: "data/create.php",
                    type: "PUT"
                }
```

Your Read and update both are using same php file.

and what is type `PUT` in create?

Just change the update url to other php file and get the posted values to run the query in the database.
and change the type of create also to POST as u are using POST for others too..

Under the Update section change this

```
url: "data/ussd.php",
```

in to

```
url: "data/update.php",
```

and try to get the posted values as i said before. see if works for you.